# How does a CD-ROM rotor know when to stop the moving plate?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, raspberry-pi

I need to make a mechanism with a RaspberryPi like in CD-ROMs, so I can easily move a plate from the minimum position (CD-Rom closed)  to maximum (CD-ROM open). I have a DC motor (from CD-ROM) and I can only tell it to turn around a given angle. I've also tried using the CD-ROM itself, but it is far to big.
How can I determine if the plate reached minimum or maximum? Or maybe I can modify the CD-ROM to make the mechanism smaller (I have a lot of them so I can experiment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method is limit switches.  Have a reversible drive mechanism and put limit switches at each end.  These can be wired in series with the driving power in a normally closed configuration to physically remove power at the stops.  Or the switches can be used as logic inputs to tell the micro to stop.  With a double pole switch it might be best to do both, to keep from accidentally powering the drive past the stops.

Using an RC servo might be an easy solution, with the position controlled by pulse width.  Alternatively, you can use a potentiometer attached to your drive mechanism as a servo does to get position feedback.  This would run into an ADC input or separate external ADC chip.  It would give you more feedback at to actual position, but be less accurate at the stops.

If you are unfamiliar with driving a motor both directions from a logic output, you might want to look at an H-bridge.  This allows reversible drive from logic inputs.

Comment: Another common approach would be to limit the current to the motor (so it won't break anything if it reaches an end stop) and either sense when the motor current reaches the limit (ignoring the over-current indicator briefly when starting the motor) or else drive it for a fixed length of time and figure it should travel fully.

Answer (score 1):

Well an ad-hoc solution would be to look for current spikes. When you want to move someting in a direction but it can't it will take more current. If you measure that you can say when you reached the endpoint. It is not elegant or precise, but depending on the application it can do the work.

You would just have to set a condition that the current is higher than \$x\$ for the time \$t\$. If you have experience with electrical protection you can of course do something akin to a overcurrent protection with time zones.

It's a bit of a duct-tape solution(if it even works), but you need no additional hardware :-)

EDIT: I just saw that supercat suggested the same thing. If you vote up this please vote up his comment too.